# How to recover from an exception with ServiceStack RabbitMQ RPC

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

Given the following code in a ServiceStack web service project:

```
public object Post(LeadInformation request)
{
    if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

    try
    {
        var msgId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var profiler = Profiler.Current;
        using (profiler.Step("Direct Api LeadInformation POST {0}".Fmt(msgId)))
        {

            var domainRequest = Mapper.Map<Leads.ServiceModel.Api.DirectApi.LeadInformationInfo>(request);

            LeadInformationResponse response;
            using (var client = base.MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
            {
                var replyToMq = client.GetTempQueueName();
                using (profiler.Step("request message {0}".Fmt(msgId)))
                {
                    var requestMsg = new Message<Leads.ServiceModel.Api.DirectApi.LeadInformationInfo>(domainRequest)
                    {
                        ReplyTo = replyToMq,
                        Id = msgId,
                    };
                    client.Publish<Leads.ServiceModel.Api.DirectApi.LeadInformationInfo>(requestMsg);    
                }

                using (profiler.Step("response message {0}".Fmt(msgId)))
                {
                    var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
                    // IMessageQueueClient.Get sleeps the thread for 100ms, lets wait for a total of x seconds

                    var responseMsg = client.Get<Leads.ServiceModel.Api.DirectApi.LeadInformationInfoResponse>(replyToMq, timeOut);

                    var domainResponse = responseMsg.GetBody();

                    if (domainResponse.ResponseStatus != null)
                    {
                        client.Nak(responseMsg, false);
                    }
                    client.Ack(responseMsg);
                    response = Mapper.Map<LeadInformationResponse>(domainResponse);
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _log.Error(exception);
        throw;
    }         
}
```

And a windows service hosting ServiceStack (2 Versions, same outcome):

**Version1**

Call a web service in another process which may die and return null or an exception

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformationInfo>(m =>
{
    try
    {
        repository.SaveMessage(m as Message);
        LeadInformationInfo response;
        using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(settingsFactory.GetMasterSetting("ProcessorApi:baseUri")))
        {
            response = client.Post<LeadInformationInfo>(m.GetBody());
        }
        return response; // will cause RabbitMQ to hang if null
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _log.Error("RegisterHandler<LeadInformationInfo>", exception);
        throw;
    }
}, 1);
```

**Version2**

Call a service that is in-process

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformationInfo>(m =>
{
    var db = container.Resolve<IRepository>();
    db.SaveMessage(m as Message);
    var response = ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m);
    return response; // will cause RabbitMQ to hang if null
}, 4);
```

You'll notice that if you return null to simulate a NullReferenceException somewhere down the line during processing, the RabbitMQ temporary queue just stays in an 'running' state vs. 'idle', it stays in this hung state as illustrated by this image.

[image: this image].

The queue will stay in this state indefinitely, only way to remedy this situation is to recycle the RabbitMQ windows service, or the hosting process, either way won't work well in a production environment. I've tried setting a timeout, but that doesn't seem to work as expected in this case.

How do I reliably recover from this problem?

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Are you calling this service from a MQ Client with a `ReplyTo`? Can you also add the code used to call this Service?

Comment: No, I left that out for brevity, it's the fact that you return null from the Handler that causes the hang.

Comment: What do you mean by Hang? The Queue is just in an active state or does it cause the Service to hang as well, i.e. is the Worker still able to process messages? Also can you tell me if you're calling this on the client with a `ReplyTo` or not? (Not if "No" means it's not, or that you prefer not to add the client code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior when the response is `null`, since the typical Response type for the Service is unknown, the [Request DTO is published to the .out MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#message-workflow).

This behavior also included client `ReplyTo` Requests, but have since changed it [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/421f33b417f709b967e5c08f6b6342c4783e5770) to publish the Request DTO back to the clients `ReplyTo` MQ.

Whilst this change should now clean-up the exclusive temporary Reply MQ created by the client, it means that only the **Request DTO** is returned and not the **Response DTO** that the client would typically expect. This behavior is visible in these [null Response MQ Tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/421f33b417f709b967e5c08f6b6342c4783e5770/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Messaging/RabbitMqServerTests.cs#L479) and can be avoided if your handler returned an Empty Response DTO. Although the normal behavior would be for the exception bubble and be published in the Requests DLQ.

The change to publish `null` responses back to the ReplyMQ is available from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Using this https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/tree/master/src/RabbitMqTest code, updated with MyGet packages, I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: To clarify, that would be the Server project that has the handler that returns null

Comment: What about the original timeout value not being honored?

Comment: @Stephen Do you mean the [Test RabbitMQ Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/RabbitMqTest/RabbitMqTest.Server/Program.cs)? That doesn't return null, can you point to the specific line of code (GitHub lets you link to line numbers). Otherwise feel free to update the Test project with a pull-request.

Comment: Yes, if you remove the HelloRabbitResponse and instead return null from the RegisterHandler, you'll see what I'm talking about. I'm also adding 2 web projects to the PR to simulate longer lived applications.